# Parsing JSON with PHP Amazon Api 5

Tags: php, json

I try to get the DisplayValues from Json code with PHP but I can't do it.

```
{
    "ItemInfo": {
        "Features": {
            "Label": "Features",
            "Locale": "en_US",
            "DisplayValues": [
                "Vented clear cover doubles as a 6-quart capacity popcorn bowl",
                "Stir rod is motorized and improves popping, get more popped corn, larger kernels per batch",
                "Convenient nesting lid is ideal for small storage"
            ]
        }
    }
```

To get Locale I do this:

```
// Convert JSON string to Array
$someArray = json_decode($response, true);

$productosMaximos = count($someArray['SearchResult']['Items']);

$productosMaximosResta = ($productosMaximos - 1);

if($productosMaximos <= 8){
    
    $productosMaximosFuncion = $productosMaximosResta;
}else{
    $productosMaximosFuncion = 7 ;
}

for ($i = 0; $i <= $productosMaximosFuncion; $i++) {

echo $someArray['SearchResult']['Items'][$i]['ItemInfo']['Features']['Locale'];
}
```

Json code its from Amazon API 5, here are the all json that i can obtain.

```
{ 
 "SearchResult": {
  "Items": [
   {
    "ASIN": "0545162076",
    "DetailPageURL": "https://www.amazon.com/dp/0545162076?tag=dgfd&linkCode=osi",
    "Images": {
       /* Container for Images Resources if requested*/
    },
    "ItemInfo": {
       /* Container for ItemInfo Resources if requested */
    },
    "Offers": {
       /* Container for Offers Resources if requested */
    },
    {
       /* More items */
    }
   }
  ],
 }
}
```

For more information can find here: https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/search-items.html
If you need more information please tell me and I give you all information that i know. Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: You haven't shown the `['SearchResult']['Items'][$i]` part of your JSON so there is no way to know.

Comment: I edited the code

Comment: No, you don't show the JSON `{ "SearchResult": { "Items": [` stuff if that's what it is.

Comment: I updated the code